# How to move files via SSH from Hostgator to Godaddy directly? Possible?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

It's my first time using SSH and so far I managed to connect via SSH to my Hostgator server. What I aim to do is to move files from my Hostgator account, to my Godaddy hosting account and file size is about 1Gb so FTP is out of the question since it would take forever (I tried earlier with FTP).

Now I'm trying to setup a SSH tunnel directly between my Hostgator and Godaddy so I can transfer files directly and much faster, but I'm stuck in this part.

Should I open two SSH sessions? Could you experienced geeks help move me in the right direction? I did research for a few hours and I still feel like I'm lost in this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSH connect to your Godaddy server. Then once you've done that `cd` to whatever directory you want the files to be copied to. Next open an sftp session to your Hostgator account using the command:

```
sftp -P [port-number] <address-of-hostgator-server>
```

The port number is the port that you use when you SSH to the server normally. If you don't usually specify a port when connecting the default is 22.

From there you can download the files to the godaddy sever using the `cd` command to find the files/directories you want and then the `get` command on the file or directory you want to download them.

Note: This will not work if the Godaddy servers have a firewall rule blocking port 22 (or whatever port you use to connect to hostgator) outbound in which case you're out of luck, you'll need to download the files locally and then upload them again.

**Some Theory**

To copy files from one host to another you can't copy files from SSH by itself, you need to use something like `sftp` or `wget`. In this case sftp is the easiest option because it is already installed on whatever linux host you are using and if the target server has SSH enabled you can use it.

When you SSH from your computer that you are working on to the GoDaddy server, any commands you run inside of that SSH shell are now being run on that GoDaddy server. By using the `sftp` command inside of this shell you create a connection between the GoDaddy server and the Hostgator server which you can control through the SSH shell you have open to GoDaddy. In essence you are using SSH to control the GoDaddy server which is using sftp to communicate with the Hostgator server.

**Actually Doing It**

To answer your example from the comments, you SSH to the GoDaddy server, then `cd` to wherever you want to the new files to go. Then once you've done that open the connection to the hostgator server using the command you proposed.

```
sftp -P 2222 username@my_server_ip
```

Now your SSH prompt should change to an `sftp>` prompt. This means that any commands you run now are commands for the sftp connection between the GoDaddy server and the Hostgator server. Now `cd` to wherever the "test" directory is on the Hostgator server and use `get -r test` to download that directory which will copy it to the GoDaddy server. Then type `exit` into the sftp prompt returning you to the SSH prompt for the GoDaddy server where you will now find your files.

Comment: I think Hostgator doesn't allow incoming connections on port 22 by default.  For my account, I have to use `-p 2222`  to get in.

Comment: @JimLewis Point taken, since OP was able to SSH to the server I assume they know what port to use.

Comment: yeah, Hostgator uses port 2222. I'm trying to connect now and will let you know later how it went. Thanks.

Comment: I need one more clarification:

if I wanted to copy the "test" directory which is on Hostgator, can I use something like this while I'm SSH conected on Godaddy? 
And should I type this on the same SSH terminal window on which I'm connected?
 
sftp -p 2222 username@my_server_ip /domains/test/

Comment: @AlboBest I've clarified my answer with some edits, does that make sense now?

Comment: yeah thanks @Wolf , it's so much more clear now after the edits. Tried using 
sftp -p 2222 username@my_server_ip

but I'm getting an error "illegal option -- p"
looking on Google isn't returning any helpful tip. What does this mean? Do you have any suggestion on this error? 
Sorry to bother you with many questions, I hope this thread will be helpful for others later too :)

Comment: @AlboBest My bad, the `p` in `-p` needs to be capitalized: `-P`.

Comment: thanks so much @BadWolf terrific work, and very patient (through chat). A little bit later, I'm going to post here exactly what worked for me other people may find it useful (and recognize you as a SSH master) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh to connect to one of the machines. For example:

```
$ ssh <username>@<godaddy-server>
```

Then from that machine, use scp to copy files across machines. For example, to transfer the file from godaddy to your home directory on hostgator:

```
$ scp <file-on-godaddy> <username>@<hostgator-server>:~
```

The -r option can be used with scp to transfer directories. In the preceding example, the colon separates the remote machine's address from the path the file will be copied to. In the example, ~ was used to transfer to the home directory.